# Angular Typescript Map to JSON

Tags: json, angular, typescript

How can I use JSON.stringify with a Typescript Map.  The presumption is the Map keys are all strings.

In this example, the console output is an empty {}

```
const myMap = new Map<string, Employee>();
myMap.set('employee1', new Employee());
myMap.set('employee2', new Employee());
myMap.set('employee3', new Employee());

console.log('myMap', JSON.stringify(myMap));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this way you can stringify the Map value

```js
 JSON.stringify([...myMap])
```

and if you want to convert the value back to Map

```js
 let obj = JSON.parse(stringifyValue)
 let myMap = new Map();
 for (let k of Object.keys(obj)) {
   myMap.set(k, obj[k]);
 }
```

check this [Converting ES6 Maps to and from JSON](https://2ality.com/2015/08/es6-map-json.html)